# OMA lightweight M2M supported Devices

Tags: device, oma

I wanted to know what mobile devices(Mobile phone and others) are available in the market which supports  OMA Lightweight M2M protocol. As its a new protocol released this year but there is no information on the internet about available devices those support this protocol. As i wanted to make Proof of concept therefore i need to have device to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMA LWM2M is indeed so new that it is not yet an official OMA  enabler.
You can find an open source implementation here: [liblwm2m](https://github.com/01org/liblwm2m). It is not feature complete (bootstrap interface is missing) but you can make proof of concept out of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the asnwer. But do you know which device is used to run this open source implementation

Comment: I use it on various Linux devices from desktop to BeagleBoards. The code should be portable to any POSIX compliant system.

Answer (score 1):

The complete Lightweight M2M spec is now available for free from OMA at http://openmobilealliance.hs-sites.com/lightweight-m2m-specification-from-oma

Answer (score 1):

Currently, OMA try to provide many helps to the developers. You can refer to https://github.com/OpenMobileAlliance
And there are some open sources as refer to 
http://www.omaevents.org/?page_id=1626 which is recent event.